# How to select all tr having a specefic background-color inside a tbody

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a table with certain tr having a special background-color

```
<table>
<tbody id="tbodyProjectList">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>wildlife</td>
<td>archived</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#4F4F4F">
<td>Xperia Z</td>
<td>archived</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Manchester</td>
<td>Running</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr style="background-color:#4F4F4F">
<td>Restored</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using jquery I want to get that all tr having that color #4f4f4f.
I did this code

```
$("#tbodyProjectList").find("tr[background-color:#404040]");
```

also did this too

```
$("#tbodyProjectList").find("tr background-color:#404040");
```

but not working. the object is empty. when I executed this in firebug it returns object[]

Comment: because it is not an attribute or an element selector. Why are you not using a class?

Comment: @epascarello - you could actually use the attributes selector for this, but it seems like a really bad idea, one of the worst ideas I've seen even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using attribute equals selector, the selector should be:

```
$("#tbodyProjectList").find("tr[style='background-color:#404040']");
```

But the selector can easily fail if you add other styles to the elements, the better here is using the `.filter()` method:

```
$("#tbodyProjectList tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(79, 79, 79)'; 
});
```

Note that you can use classes for filtering the elements, selecting the elements based on the CSS properties is a bad idea.

Comment: and if there is there is another thing in the style? (I know the example does not)

Comment: Then you use the better option `.css('background-color')` he suggested

Comment: Do all browsers give rgb?

Comment: Nope, most modern browsers support RGBA

Comment: Thankyou, I got answer from the second code block by eliminating one '=' symbol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$('#tbodyProjectList tr[style*=background-color:#404040]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for find tr that have specific background-color

$('tr').filter(function(){ if($(this).css('background-color')=="#4F4F4F")return $(this);})